# Generate Faker data from python and load it into BigQuery nested table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-bigquery

I wanted to create dummy data for my testing. So I have created some dummy data by using `faker` then I have loaded that obj into pandas dataframe. But my target BigQuery table has nested array.

And I need to do some calculations on faker object, like if the `destination` is `'sometext'`then `route` should be empty else add `origin` and `destination`.

below is my existing code.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import pandas as pd
from faker import Factory
import random
import uuid
import string
import datetime
from datetime import date

def test():
    return{ 'user_uuid':uuid.uuid4(),
            'origin':random.choice(airport) ,
            'destination':random.choice(airport),
            'route':  'origin' + 'destination',
            'app': {'version':'','model':{'name':''},'id':'','type':''},
            'passenger':{'title':'','firstname':'','lastname':''},
            'datetime':'',
            }

example_dummy_data = pd.DataFrame([test() for _ in range(2)])

pandas_gbq.to_gbq(example_dummy_data, 'dataset.table', project_id='project', if_exists='append')
```

My table structure

```
[
  {
    "name": "user_uuid",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
  },
  {
    "name": "origin",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
  },
  {
    "name": "destination",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
  },
  {
    "name": "route",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
  },
  {
    "name": "app",
    "type": "RECORD",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "version",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
      },
      {
       "name": "model",
       "type": "RECORD",
       "mode": "REPEATED",
       "fields": [
          {
          "name": "name",
          "type": "STRING",
          "mode": "NULLABLE"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "id",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
      },
      {
        "name": "type",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "customer",
    "type": "RECORD",
    "mode": "REPEATED",
    "fields": [
   {
        "name": "title",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "firstname",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "lastname",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "datetime",
    "type": "TIMESTAMP",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
  }

]
```

I need some better suggestions according to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pandas_gbq` library does not support nested or repeated fields.

You can try using the `google-cloud-bigquery` library instead, which supports those fieldst. You can find details on how to load DataFrames into BigQuery using this library [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/pandas-gbq-migration#loading_a_pandas_dataframe_to_a_table).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have replaced pandas with GCP library.

Comment: `dataset_ref = client.dataset('DATASET'], 'project')
table_ref = dataset_ref.table('TABLE')
table = client.get_table(table_ref)  # Make an API request.
rows_to_insert = [ func() for _ in range(num)]
errors = client.insert_rows(table, rows_to_insert)  # Make an API request.
if errors == []:
    print("New rows have been added.")  `

Comment: So, has it worked using `google-cloud-bigquery`? If so, you can indicate it by accepting the answer. If not, what issues are you having?